# How to exclude files when compressing using 7zip GUI parameters

Tags: 7zip

I am trying to compress a folder with 7zip and I am using the 7zip GUI, but I want to exclude some files that I have already defined in an excludelist.txt file. I am trying to put this in the Parameters option of the GUI:

```
-x@"D:\Projects Backup\excludelist.lst"
```

But I am getting this error:

> The parameter is incorrect

[image: 7zip GUI]
[image: Error Adding Parameters]

Answer (score 15):

The "Parameters" input in the GUI is misleading: it can only contain compression parameters (i.e., whatever comes after the `-m` command line switch), not command line arguments. There is no way to exclude files using the GUI yet, but [the main dev thinks about it](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/6cd7fcd8/)...

Your only solution is to use the command line version or another 7-zip GUI.